# Como faço para salvar alterações de dados decimais em C#

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, winforms, replace, decimal

Fiz um winform para gestão de dados, quando eu faço alterações desses dados a partir da textbox e salvo as alterações, os número após a vírgula e a própria vírgula que foram salvos não são apresentados na textbox.

linha do código:
private void Btn_Salvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
d.capitalinteriorinteira = decimal.Parse(Tb_CapitalInteriorInteira.Text);
}

Já tentei o replace para substituir a Vírgula pelo ponto e ser salvo com o ponto mas apenas exclui a vírgula, No banco de dados: 1023 mas apresentados no TxtBox: 1023
linha do código
d.capitalinteriorinteira = decimal.Parse(Tb_CapitalInteriorInteira.Text.Replace(",","."));

OBS1: A primeira vez que eu incluo os dados ele é apresentado normalmente

OBS1.0: Esses dados incluídos apresentados normalmente entram no banco de dados com ponto ao invés da vírgula EX: 10.23 mas apresentados no TxtBox: 10,23

OBS2: Os dados decimais que excluem a vírgula e os números após a vírgula, estão no banco de dados com a vírgula EX:10,23 mas apresentados no TxtBox: 10

Comment: Qual o tipo de dado desse cara `d.capitalinteriorinteira` ?

Comment: ele para ser apresentado no textbox foi convertido para string(decimal > string)

Answer (score -2):

Não entendi exatamente a pergunta, mas você pode fazer isso para obter o valor do textbox:

```
double dAux = double.Parse(textBox.Text);
```

E então na tabela SQL você declara o campo como float e basta dar um insert desta variável dAux para o DB.

Comment: eu tenho os dados e gostaria de altera-los, mas quando eu altero eu não consigo com que faça que ele seja mostrado por inteiro, por exemplo se eu salvei como 10,43 ele aparece na textbox como 10 sendo que tem o resto, e não posso trabalhar com outro tipo de dado a não ser o decimal já que é moeda